# change border radius of mat-flat-button on angular

Tags: css, angular, button, angular-material

I am developing an angular app and would like to change the border radius of mat-flat-button. I am able to change the background color of the button using css, but not the border radius. my code

```
    <div  flexLayout = "row">
                    <button class="flat_button" (click)="toggle_color()" mat-flat-button>B2-L1</button>
                    <button mat-flat-button>B2-L3</button>
                    <button mat-flat-button>B2-L3</button>
                    <button mat-flat-button>B2-L4</button>

    </div>
```

.css

```
 .mat-flat-button {
      background-color: grey;
      border-radius: 0 px;  
  }

  .mat-button {
    border-radius: 0 px;     
  }
```

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

The material buttons usually have the same class added to the button. If you assign some style to the button class it should reflect on screen. try as below:

```
.mat-button, 
.mat-flat-button, 
.mat-icon-button, 
.mat-stroked-button { 
  border-radius: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: `.mat-button, .mat-flat-button, .mat-icon-button, .mat-stroked-button {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }`